# I got No overload matches this call problem when I create server hostname in typescript

Tags: typescript

I tried to create a new server in a typescript file, but it gave me an alert.

> No overload matches this call.
>
> The last overload gave the following error.   Argument of type
> 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2769)
>
> net.d.ts(480, 9): The last overload is declared here.

My code

```
   const port: string | number = process.env.PORT || 9999;
   const host = '127.0.0.1';
   http.createServer((req, res) => {
   }).listen(port, host, () => {
   console.log(`I'm listening host: ${host} & port: ${port}`)
   })
```

and I went to net.d.ts(480, 9), I believe I match one of these function

```
 listen(port?: number, hostname?: string, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument `port` for the function `listen` can only be a number if present, so you have to cast the env variable to a number:

```js
import http from 'http';

const port: number = Number(process.env.PORT) || 9999;
const host = "127.0.0.1";

http
  .createServer((req, res) => {})
  .listen(port, host, () => {
    console.log(`I'm listening host: ${host} & port: ${port}`);
  });
```

In order for your current code to work, there would have to be an overload that allows for `port` to be `number | string`:

```
listen(port?: number | string, hostname?: string, listeningListener?: () => void): this;
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought the problem was the hostname, I was wrong.